# +/- operators for dates in SpEL

Tags: operators, spring-3, addition, subtraction, spring-el

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html), + and - operators can be used on dates in SpEL. However, I couldn't find neither the meaning/signature of these ops nor an example. Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in the documentation. I opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11057).